# Sort a group with specified value at the end

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to order a group in Crystal Reports 2016, with a value that should be shown at the end of the group.

For example, these are the values (strings) from the group:

B
A
C
D
E

I want to put "C" at the end and the rest ascending, like this:

A
B
D
E
C

My SQL expression is already sorting it in the desired order, but that doesn't work.
I tried it with "Specified Order", but the value C would be the first record.
Also the formula on Groupoptions for sorting with checkbox "Use Formula for Groupordering.." doesn't work for me, because i can't even select the databasefield...

(I'm using the german version of crystal reports, the exact description of the elements may be different)

How could i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If your query already returns the correct order , just use "in original order." instead of specified